# PHP function is little strange

Tags: php, function

I coded like this.

```
<?php 
function get_argument($arg){
    return $arg;
}
echo print get_argument(33);
?>
```

saved as php extension file.
And execute it in chrome. I expected that it print out the number '33'

But it tells me '331'

little strange to me. So I change the value 34, instead of 33.

It print out '341'

So I tested it one more time.

Insert two more code like this.

```
echo get_argument(33);
print get_argument(33);
```

Both of them print out the same number, which is '33'

What is difference? What causes it a little, but big result?

Comment: `echo` and `print` are both outputting your arguments. Stop using both.

Comment: why you are using print inside echo?

Comment: It's just an experiment :-)

Answer (score 8):

Because print has return, see at PHP documentation: http://php.net/print.

Answer (score 6):

Because when you write `echo print get_argument(33);` , it'll execute the **print** first, so the print will write 33.

But, the print will return 1, which is then printed by the echo

Answer (score 3):

When you type

```
echo print get_argument(33);
```

it first prints the result of `get_argument(33)` as 33, and then echoes the result of `print get_argument(33)` as true which is 1.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are using echo and print at the same time, chosse only one.

```
<?php 
  function get_argument($arg){
   return $arg;
  }
   print get_argument(33);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

in this command echo print get_argument(33) : you are 2 output first is : 
print get_argument(33)

and second is echo ;

echo will return result of print function;
1 is for result of print function.

Answer (score -2):

i am not sure why it happens but try to return integer

```
function get_argument($arg){
    return intval($arg);
}
```

Comment: Not an answer - see the PHP reference on `print`